# How to place pictures inside parcolumns

Tags: columns, parcolumns

I would like to display pictures inside \colchunk of parcolumns. This works just fine, but it produces a vertical space in the oppposite column. How can I prevent this from happening?

```
\begin{parcolumns}[rulebetween,colwidths={1=0.4\linewidth}]{2}

\colchunk{%
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
}

\colchunk{%
\lipsum[1]

\begin{minipage}{1\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Image}\captionof{figure}{Caption}
\end{minipage}

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
}

\end{parcolumns}
```

This code gives the follwoing output:
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't mind to switch from the old package `parcolumns` to a newest one like [`paracol`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/paracol), you won't have this kind of problems...

Note that, if you want, you can even use floating environments inside the columns, as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin]{babel} % only for the example

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\columnratio{0.4,0.6}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{2em}
\begin{leftcolumn}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\end{leftcolumn}

\begin{rightcolumn}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Image}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\end{rightcolumn}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

What to know to migrate to `paracol`:

- To obtain the same result of

  ```
  \begin{parcolumns}[rulebetween,colwidths={1=0.4\linewidth}]{2}
  ```

  you have to write

  ```
  \columnratio{0.4,0.6}
  \begin{paracol}{2}
  \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
  \setlength{\columnsep}{2em}
  ```

  The last two can be put outside the `paracol` environment if you want the changes to be global.
- Instead of using

  ```
  \colchunk{......}
  ```

  you have to use

  ```
  \begin{leftcolumn}
  ......
  \end{leftcolumn}
  ```

  for the left column, and

  ```
  \begin{rightcolumn}
  ......
  \end{rightcolumn}
  ```

  for the right column.

Many more options can be found in its [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/paracol/paracol-man.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, I think there's no reason not to switch to a new package.

Comment: @ThreeDog You're welcome. IMHO, `paracol` is by far much better than `parcolumns`.

Comment: +1. But your last sentence links to the documentation of `paracolumns`, not `paracol`.