# paracol and KOMA: Weird Text Color Related Behaviour Depending on Page Break

Tags: koma-script, paracol

> ### Final Update (2018-05-18)
>
> Version 1.34 of `paracol` with the fix related to this question is availabe on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/paracol) now.

- I use a KOMA document class in combination with the `paracol` package.
- The final purpose of the document is a bilingual document (two languages, two synchronized columns).
- In my real document, I color the heading of level `subparagraph` (here I use red). **\addtokomafont{subparagraph}{\color{red}}**
- My problem is that the color of the `subparagraph` on some page break circumstances produces that the normal text is also colored.
- I have trouble narrowing down the problem and making the code minimal: Different page break and the problem/effect is gone.

---

```
% Dokumentenklasse inkl. Optionen
\documentclass[
    fontsize = 12pt
    ,headings = small
    ,parskip = true
    ,numbers = noendperiod
    ,chapterprefix = true
    ]{scrbook}

%% Seitenlayout
\usepackage[
    %showframe = true,
    showframe = false,
        ]{geometry}

% Seiten-Dimensionen
\geometry{paperwidth = 300mm} % Format 16:9
\geometry{paperheight = 168.75mm} % Format 16:9
\geometry{margin = 15mm}
\geometry{marginparsep = 2mm}
\geometry{marginparwidth = 8mm}
\geometry{footskip = 14mm}

% Color Support
\usepackage{xcolor}

% paracol
\usepackage{paracol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{2em}

\addtokomafont{subparagraph}{\color{red}}

% http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/10289/wie-andere-ich-die-abstande-uberunter-section-subsection-subsubsection
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip = 0\baselineskip,
  afterskip = 1\baselineskip,
  innerskip = 0\baselineskip]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip = 0\baselineskip,
  afterskip = 0.25\baselineskip]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip = 0\baselineskip,
  afterskip = 1sp]{subparagraph}

%% Dummy-Texte
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Heading}

% ### ### ###
\begin{paracol}{2}
% --- --- ---
\begin{leftcolumn*}
    % --- ---
    \section{Section Heading Left}
    \subparagraph{Subparagraph Heading Left}
    % ---

    \blindtext 
    \vspace{10mm}

    % ---
    % --- ---
\end{leftcolumn*}
% --- --- ---

% --- --- ---
\begin{rightcolumn}
    % --- ---
    \section*{Section Heading Right}
    \subparagraph*{Subparagraph Heading Right (Without Numbering)}
    % ---

    \blindtext

    % ---
    % --- ---
\end{rightcolumn}

% --- --- ---
\begin{leftcolumn*}
    % --- ---
    \section{Section Heading Left}
    \subparagraph*{Subparagraph Heading Right (Without Numbering)}
    % ---

    \blindtext

    % ---
    % --- ---
\end{leftcolumn*}
% --- --- ---

% --- --- ---
\begin{rightcolumn}
    % --- ---
    \section*{Section Heading Right (Without Numbering)}
    \subparagraph*{Subparagraph Heading Right (Without Numbering)}
    % ---

    \blindtext

    % ---
    % --- ---
\end{rightcolumn}
% --- --- ---
\end{paracol}
% ### ### ###

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Now I edit one line of code, e. g. comment `\geometry{margin = 15mm}` and get no red normal text:

```
% Dokumentenklasse inkl. Optionen
\documentclass[
    fontsize = 12pt
    ,headings = small
    ,parskip = true
    ,numbers = noendperiod
    ,chapterprefix = true
    ]{scrbook}

%% Seitenlayout
\usepackage[
    %showframe = true,
    showframe = false,
        ]{geometry}

% Seiten-Dimensionen
\geometry{paperwidth = 300mm} % Format 16:9
\geometry{paperheight = 168.75mm} % Format 16:9
%\geometry{margin = 15mm}
\geometry{marginparsep = 2mm}
\geometry{marginparwidth = 8mm}
\geometry{footskip = 14mm}

% Color Support
\usepackage{xcolor}

% paracol
\usepackage{paracol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{2em}

\addtokomafont{subparagraph}{\color{red}}

% http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/10289/wie-andere-ich-die-abstande-uberunter-section-subsection-subsubsection
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip = 0\baselineskip,
  afterskip = 1\baselineskip,
  innerskip = 0\baselineskip]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip = 0\baselineskip,
  afterskip = 0.25\baselineskip]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip = 0\baselineskip,
  afterskip = 1sp]{subparagraph}

%% Dummy-Texte
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Heading}

% ### ### ###
\begin{paracol}{2}
% --- --- ---
\begin{leftcolumn*}
    % --- ---
    \section{Section Heading Left}
    \subparagraph{Subparagraph Heading Left}
    % ---

    \blindtext 
    \vspace{10mm}

    % ---
    % --- ---
\end{leftcolumn*}
% --- --- ---

% --- --- ---
\begin{rightcolumn}
    % --- ---
    \section*{Section Heading Right}
    \subparagraph*{Subparagraph Heading Right (Without Numbering)}
    % ---

    \blindtext

    % ---
    % --- ---
\end{rightcolumn}

% --- --- ---
\begin{leftcolumn*}
    % --- ---
    \section{Section Heading Left}
    \subparagraph*{Subparagraph Heading Right (Without Numbering)}
    % ---

    \blindtext

    % ---
    % --- ---
\end{leftcolumn*}
% --- --- ---

% --- --- ---
\begin{rightcolumn}
    % --- ---
    \section*{Section Heading Right (Without Numbering)}
    \subparagraph*{Subparagraph Heading Right (Without Numbering)}
    % ---

    \blindtext

    % ---
    % --- ---
\end{rightcolumn}
% --- --- ---
\end{paracol}
% ### ### ###

\end{document}
```

---

I know that the code is not minimal enough to pass a MWE test. I have trouble providing it.

[image]

---

### Update: Numbered SubParagraph

I made my "MWE" too minimal: I forgot that I have numbered `subparagraph` . When I incorporate David's code in the originally provided example then I get the desired behaviour.

**When I have numbered subparagraph, then the number is not colored.**

```
% Dokumentenklasse inkl. Optionen
\documentclass[
    fontsize = 12pt
    ,headings = small
    ,parskip = true
    ,numbers = noendperiod
    ,chapterprefix = true
    ]{scrbook}

%% Seitenlayout
\usepackage[
    %showframe = true,
    showframe = false,
        ]{geometry}

% Seiten-Dimensionen
\geometry{paperwidth = 300mm} % Format 16:9
\geometry{paperheight = 168.75mm} % Format 16:9
\geometry{margin = 15mm}
\geometry{marginparsep = 2mm}
\geometry{marginparwidth = 8mm}
\geometry{footskip = 14mm}

% Color Support
\usepackage{xcolor}

% paracol
\usepackage{paracol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{2em}

% subparagraph is numberes
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

% Code from David
% -------------------------
\makeatletter
\def\zzz{%
\long\def\sectionlinesformat##1##2##3##4{%
\@hangfrom {\hskip ##2##3}{\textcolor{red}{##4}}}}
\makeatother

\addtokomafont{subparagraph}{\zzz}
%\addtokomafont{subparagraph}{\color{red}}
% -------------------------

% http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/10289/wie-andere-ich-die-abstande-uberunter-section-subsection-subsubsection
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip = 0\baselineskip,
  afterskip = 1\baselineskip,
  innerskip = 0\baselineskip]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip = 0\baselineskip,
  afterskip = 0.25\baselineskip]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip = 0\baselineskip,
  afterskip = 1sp]{subparagraph}

%% Dummy-Texte
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Heading}

% ### ### ###
\begin{paracol}{2}
% --- --- ---
\begin{leftcolumn*}
    % --- ---
    \section{Section Heading Left}
    \subparagraph{Subparagraph Heading Left}
    % ---

    \blindtext 
    \vspace{10mm}

    % ---
    % --- ---
\end{leftcolumn*}
% --- --- ---

% --- --- ---
\begin{rightcolumn}
    % --- ---
    \section*{Section Heading Right}
    \subparagraph*{Subparagraph Heading Right (Without Numbering)}
    % ---

    \blindtext

    % ---
    % --- ---
\end{rightcolumn}

% --- --- ---
\begin{leftcolumn*}
    % --- ---
    \section{Section Heading Left}
    \subparagraph{Subparagraph Heading Right (Without Numbering)}
    % ---

    \blindtext

    % ---
    % --- ---
\end{leftcolumn*}
% --- --- ---

% --- --- ---
\begin{rightcolumn}
    % --- ---
    \section*{Section Heading Right (Without Numbering)}
    \subparagraph*{Subparagraph Heading Right (Without Numbering)}
    % ---

    \blindtext

    % ---
    % --- ---
\end{rightcolumn}
% --- --- ---
\end{paracol}
% ### ### ###

\end{document}
```

[image]

> ### Update (2018-04-27)
>
> I contacted the author of KOMA ([Markus Kohm](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script), Germany) and here's
>   summary of what he recommended.
>
> - Better use `\sbox` instead of `\setbox`.
> - Or use  `\color@begingroup` and `\color@endgroup` when using `\setbox`.
> - The definition of `\sbox` shows how it should/could be done.
> - In the case of `paracol` (mad box tricks that span multiple pages) you need to take care of *color stack*.
>
> I also contacted the author of the `paracol` package ([Hiroshi
>   Nakashima](http://www.para.media.kyoto-u.ac.jp/), Japan). He wants to look into it.
>
> I also contacted [Heike Oberdiek](https://ctan.org/author/oberdiek), the author of
>   color-stack-related packages. He won't be able to look into it in
>   detail though.
>
> ### Update (2018-05-03)
>
> The author of the `paracol` package replied and it doesn't look good
>   for me :). **In short: color is a problem (in rare cases like mine) for the current version of `paracol`.**
>
> I investigated your problem to find the following. (1) The root cause
>   is in paracol (i.e., not in KOMA). (2) Fixing the bug in paracol is
>   extremely tough, though I'll try it    in future.
>
> Here I show you a little bit lengthy explanation of each issue above.
>
> (1) Root Cause Text coloring is one of toughest implementation issues
>   of paracol because, for example, we have to color some page-crossing
>   lines in left column without interference with coloring in right
>   column.  The coloring mechanism in paracol usually works well, but in
>   some unusual cases like your MWE it fails to color texts properly. 
>   More specifically, we face a trouble in the following case. (a) A
>   sequence of non-breakable lines is given when a page has too    small
>   room to have them as a whole.  In your case, the sequence    consists
>   of the heading of Section 1.2, that of subparagraph and    first two
>   lines of the ordinary paragraph. (b) The sequence has colored
>   paragraphs.  In your case, section    heading and subparagraph heading
>   are colored (with black and red)    and are one-line paragraphs. (c)
>   The sequence could be broken into two pages and the second page
>   would start with a colored paragraph, if it were breakable.  In
>   your case, TeX would find a page-break point between the section
>   and subparagraph headings. When paracol's coloring mechanism sees such
>   a sequence, it inserts a page-break point into the sequence
>   inappropriately, and misunderstands that the coloring of the first
>   line of the second page (subparagraph heading) has started in the
>   first page to cause an improper coloring (reddening all texts
>   following the subparagraph heading).
>
> (2) (Nearly) Perfect Fix Since the problem you faced reveals that the
>   fundamental idea of paracol's coloring mechanism is inappropriate,
>   fixing the bug requires to redesign the mechanism completely even if
>   it is possible.  I have an idea for the fix and will examine its
>   feasibility, but I cannot be sure when, or even whether, the fix is
>   incorporated into a future release of paracol.
>
> ### Update (2018-05-08)
>
> The author of the `paracol` package generated a new version (1.34) which will be publicly available in the coming weeks. I got the chance to test it now and with my current actual document: It works within my current document!
>
> ### Final Update (2018-05-18)
>
> Version 1.34 of `paracol` with the fix related to this question is availabe on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/paracol) now.

Comment: try to replace  `\color{red}` with `\textcolor{red}`

Comment: @touhami I will test it later. Driving now. Thanks. But textcolor needs an argument as far as I know. That is not useful in this case I think.

Comment: A way to fix this (but more a quick hacky fix, not tackling the real problem): `\newcommand*\colorblack{\color{black}}\addtokomafont{subparagraph}{\color{red}\aftergroup\colorblack}`. It works at least in the MWE you gave.

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks a lot. If you also find the real problem, my day is even brighter :).

Comment: I also run into this issue and found, that the oberdieck bundle provides some packages called pdfcol, pdfcolparallel and pdfcolparcolumns, which solved the issue. -- Just saw your edit: why don't you swap the parcol package to parallel or parcolumns and try with Heikos packages? I used KOMA-script by then.

Comment: @KeksDose Thanks for the comment. This is a good overview! I will look into the two  mentioned parallel-text packages. Before I Switch, I want to malke sure that it works (better). I also have to change a lot of already written code. . Apart from the color problem, I am very happy with `paracol` (`parcolumns ` also has it's problems: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155012, see e. g. comment from karlkoeller).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pdftex does warn you

```
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex: pop empty color page stack 0
```

If you change the definition to

```
\makeatletter
\def\zzz{%
\long\def\sectionlinesformat##1##2##3##4{%
\@hangfrom {\hskip ##2##3}{\textcolor{red}{##4}}}}
\makeatother


\addtokomafont{subparagraph}{\zzz}
```

then the red stays in the heading, without any warnings that the stack is corrupted.  the indirect definition inserts a `\textcolor`  just around the text of the heading without disturbing the heading layout code.

Comment: Wow, thanks. Do you happen to know if this is a "fault" of KOMA or paracol? I could inform the developer respectively.

Comment: I have a standard response to all artefacts of color package **It's not my fault** Koma could have a way of getting a font or color setting closer to the text but the fact that it doesn't isn't really a fault (that is, you need a feature request not a bug report) that said, it may have such a feature, I never looked at the manual , the above is reverse engineered from a trace of the setting in your example. However I didn't spot anything that looked like a documented hook @Dr.ManuelKuehner

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the quick response. I will try to contact the developer of KOMA then. Funny enough, I used the same code without paracol for about two years now in different documents without a problem.

Comment: Hello David. I forgot something - in the real document I have `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}` which leads to numbered `subparagraph`. The number is not part of the color group (not sure if thats technically the correct term) apparently. Should I ask a new question or does this qualify as an update on the question?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I'll have a look later

Comment: Hello David. The problem is not urgent. I use black and white until there may be a solution in the future. Nevertheless, if you find the time, I will appreciate it. But if I were you, I would try not to get to much reputation and destroy your perfect score of 444k :).