# change background in paracol package

Tags: backgrounds, paracol

In manual for paracol package there is example how they change background color. But there is no particular code. Is it possible to change background color for paragraph or theorem environment? And what code I can use for this.
Thank you

Comment: See the § 7.7 pag. 25 of the documentation and an example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425632/paracol-and-koma-weird-behaviour-depending-on-page-break

Comment: more exactly $7.8 . I tried code bellow before send question but I did not see any result
``` \documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{paracol}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\begin{document}

\section{S1}
\backgroundcolor{s(4pt,-4pt)}[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\begin{paracol}{1}
\backgroundcolor{s(4pt,-4pt)}[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\begin{definition}
Let $A$ be algebra.
The norm
on module $A$ such that
\[\|ab\|\le\|a\|\,\|b\|\]
is called norm on algebra $A$.
\end{definition}
\end{paracol}
abc
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, it works. I have to use ``` \backgroundcolor{c}[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}''' First parameter is c, not s. It is not clear what is span. Probably separation between columns

Comment: `paracol` enables you tro write text in parallel columns. A "spanning text" , which is what `s` refers to in the context of `background colors` here is a text than  spans both columns.

Comment: Most people use tcolorbox for this sort of thing.

Comment: I use framed or paracol because I want continue text to next page. The only problem in paracol is next. It creates footnotes as I expect. However footnotes are disconnected from footnote mark

Comment: @AleksKleyn: Would you mind adding a sketch/descrition of the expected output to your question? Are you aware that `tcolorbox` allows colored boxes than can span several pages, as well?

Comment: @leandriis For instance ``` \documentclass{amsart}
\scrollmode
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{UrlColor}{rgb}{.9,0,.3}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\UseRawInputEncoding
\begin{document}
\title{Test File}

\begin{abstract}
In this paper I consider tcolorbox.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\linewidth/2]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}```

Comment: I cannot add long code. You can copy and paste lines. Colorbox leaves first page clean and goes to second but it cannot continue to third.